# Can't download API 9 [as a solution to "google-play-services_lib, Unable to resolve target android-9"]

Tags: android, google-play-services

When trying to add **Google Play Services Library** to my Eclipse environment, I got the error

> Unable to resolve target 'android-9'

The well accredited answer given to

```
         **"Google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'"**
```

was to download **API 9 (Obsolete)** through the **SDK manager**.

However, when I did that I got the following error message:

```
 Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused
  Downloading Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples 2.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
  Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)' which was not    installed.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
```

(I do not enough points to be allowed to comment on the answer.) Any advice :) ?

Comment: Why download API 9? You need to download the latest Android SDK and always target the latest in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have the latest SDK and yet I was still getting this error message, so I figured that the latest SDK was relying on API 9 being installed already. Meanwhile though, I managed to solve the problem, AND now my SDK manager wont even give me the option to try and download API 9, for some reason.
(I have been trying so many things that I actually forgot how I solved it, so I cant write it; shame)

Comment: API 9 is obselete. If you want to download you need to click, "Show Obselete". I am telling you not to because you do not need it. Since you are starting Android development, you should be using Android Studio not Eclipse as well.